# Get sub-strings of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

for e.g : string = 'AbcDEfGhIJK'

I want to fetch a list with :
['A','bc','DE','f','G','h','IJK']

I am trying to think of a logic for doing this, but so far no luck.

EDIT : 
I don't know regex, so I just used loops
This is what I came up with, It doesn't give the last 'IJK' though

```
u_count = 0 
l_count = 0 
l_string = '' 
u_string = '' 
output = []

data = 'AbcDEfGhIJK'

for c in data:
 if(c.isupper()):
    if(l_count !=0):
        output.append(l_string)
        l_count = 0
        l_string = ''
    u_string += c
    u_count += 1

 if(c.islower()):
    if(u_count !=0):
        output.append(u_string)
        u_count = 0
        u_string = ''
    l_string +=c
    l_count += 1
print(output)
```

Comment: Try something, anything. search around for how to write the code, think of the logic on your own. A hint is that it revolves around uppercase and lowercase letters. But you have to make a sincere effort. Stackoverflow isn't a "please do my work for me" site.

Comment: Your first step is to fully understand the problem. Why is that example output the proper output for that example input? Look carefully at upper case and lower case. Only after you understand the problem do you have any hope of solving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

string = 'AbcDEfGhIJK'
out = [''.join(group) for key, group in groupby(string, key=lambda c: c.islower())]
print(out)
# ['A', 'bc', 'DE', 'f', 'G', 'h', 'IJK']
```

Here, `groupby` will group the characters that give the same output for `islower()`

Comment: This is what I was able to come up with, It doesn't return the last 'IJK' though : u_count = 0 
l_count = 0 
l_string = '' 
u_string = '' 
output = []
data = 'AbcDEfGhIJK'

for c in data:
    if(c.isupper()):
        if(l_count !=0):
            output.append(l_string)
            l_count = 0
            l_string = ''
        u_string += c
        u_count += 1
    
    if(c.islower()):
        if(u_count !=0):
            output.append(u_string)
            u_count = 0
            u_string = ''
        l_string +=c
        l_count += 1
print(output)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex:

```
import re

text = 'AbcDEfGhIJK'

result = re.split('([a-z]+)', text)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['A', 'bc', 'DE', 'f', 'G', 'h', 'IJK']
```

The idea is to split the string on lower case letters `'([a-z]+)'`, but keeping the splitting pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'AbcDEfGhIJK'
str=list(str)
for k,v in enumerate(str[:-1]):
    joined=''.join([str[k],str[k+1]])
    if joined.isupper() or joined.islower():
        str[k+1]=joined
        str[k]=''
str=[x for x in str if x!='']
print(str)
```

Output

```
['A', 'bc', 'DE', 'f', 'G', 'h', 'IJK']
```